# make_shared() calling destructor twice when giving it an already created object

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Using VS 2015 with v120.

So I am getting memory exceptions because when I call `make_shared()` on an already constructed object. The already constructed object has a pointer to another object that was allocated with `new` so when it calls the destructor the first time. The object is destroyed, then when it calls it again, the object is already destroyed.

I thought that in this instance the object will be moved and the destructor is never called.

Code:

Sub-object:

```
#include "Obj.h"

Obj::Obj(int i)
{
    cout << "const Obj " << this << "\n";
    m_i = i;
}
Obj::~Obj()
{
    cout << "-------------------DELETING  o " << this << "\n";
}
```

Containing Object:

```
#include "BigObj.h"

BigObj::BigObj(int i)
{
    cout << "const BIgObj " << this << "\n";
    m_o = new Obj(i);
}


BigObj::BigObj()
{
}

BigObj::BigObj(const BigObj& o)
{
    cout << "called copy const \n";
    m_o = o.m_o;
}

BigObj::~BigObj()
{
    delete m_o;
    cout << "----------------DEL bigobj " << this << "\n";
}
```

Main:

```
int main(char argc, char** argv){

    BigObj oo = BigObj(10);
    shared_ptr<BigObj> shr= make_shared<BigObj>(oo);

    BigObj oo2 = BigObj(100);
    cout << "finished\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Output:

```
const BIgObj 000000C61F4FFAD8
const Obj 000000C61F658330
called copy const
const BIgObj 000000C61F4FFB28
const Obj 000000C61F658510
finished
Press any key to continue . . .
-------------------DELETING  o 000000C61F658510
----------------DEL bigobj 000000C61F4FFB28
-------------------DELETING  o 000000C61F658330
----------------DEL bigobj 000000C61F65AFB0
-------------------DELETING  o 000000C61F658330
```

This is test code I made to show the problem. In the real project I create objects that need to contain a lot of info and then they are pushed onto a vector that is made shared for various threads to work on the info. This so whatever thread has the object last deletes it.

Comment: What type is `m_o`? Your copy constructor of `BigObj` seems to violate the rule of three...

Comment: Is there a reason you did not write a minimal, complete example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erm - you copy constructor (of `BigObj`) copies  the *internal pointer* (`Obj`) and then then there are two deletes on it (once the automatic instance is cleaned up and then the shared pointer) This is not good.. Copy constructor (of `BigObj`) is not doing the right thing, it should instantiate the subobject (`Obj`) using it's (of `Obj`) copy constructor...

EDIT: A clean-ish implementation..

```
class Obj
{
};

class BigObj
{
public:
  // Default constructor
  BigObj() : _obj(new Obj)
  { }
  // Move constructor
  BigObj(BigObj&& other) : _obj(move(other._obj)) // take ownership of the subobject
  { }
  // Move assignment
  BigObj& operator=(BigObj&& other)
  {
    _obj = move(other._obj); // take ownership of the subobject
    return *this;
  }
private:
  unique_ptr<Obj> _obj;
};
```

Comment: Apologies, could you tell me what I need to change. I am slightly confused. Do I need a copy constructor at all?

Comment: Depends on how you want the `BigObj` to behave, if you want to transfer the ownership of the subobject, then have a move constructor in `BigObj` and *move* instance, else in the *copy constructor* of `BigObj`, instantiate the subobject by copying the passed in instance's subobject (i.e. trigger *copy constructor* of `Obj`)

Comment: The way the real code works is. BigObj has various pointers, it is passed to several functions that make allocations and set the pointers. Then BigObj is made shared so it can be passed along. If the collection of info fails the object is just discarded. I am not making shared till I know that there is data in it.

Comment: Then you should support move semantics, i.e. your `BigObj`  should *only* have a move constructor and `delete` the copy constructor. In the move, simply take the pointers. I would also hold those subobjects in `unique_ptr` instances, as this will clarify your intentions quite a bit.

Comment: would you mind writing the move constructor. I am not quite sure how you declare one.

Comment: Anyway, all this is *moot*, from your description, there is no advantage to the approach you are describing, simply instantiate the `shared_ptr` (instead of the automatic instance), and then pass the instance by de-referencing the shared pointer to the functions that need to initialize it...

Comment: Is there not too much overhead from creating shared pointers every time? I mean, there may be no data to fill it up with.

Comment: Thanks I think I get what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
BigObj oo = BigObj(10);
shared_ptr<BigObj> shr= make_shared<BigObj>(oo);
```

Isn't doing what you think it is.  You are creating a shared pointer and putting a copy of `oo` into it.  Your copy constructor is copying `m_o`.  This now means in your `main` you have TWO `BigObj` objects:  `oo` and the newly made copy held by `shr`

Since both of their `m_o` members point at the same memory, their destructors will call delete on `m_o` twice.

You don't need `oo` first, you may construct the object in place using `make_shared`:

```
shared_ptr<BigObj> shr = make_shared<BigObj>(10);
```

This should fix your problem, but you should also look into deep versus shallow copies for why the copy constructor is problematic.

Comment: I added it to test. Do I need it at all? Removing it does not change anything. What should I do then?

Comment: @unixsnob Not sure what you're referring to -- I've made some edits to get you working

Comment: I made a comment to Nim explaining how I want the object to behave. Does it help? I can add more info.

Comment: @unixsnob Yes it does.  `make_shared` does not just create a shared_ptr, it constructs an object of type `T` then returns a `shared_ptr` to that object.  If you already have the object, you should not use `make_shared`.